# Redirect to another domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, seo, hosting

I have been building a WordPress site and uploading/testing it on a .info domain hosted by Bluehost. It has come time to launch the site, and needs to be on the .com domain. The .com domain is hosted on Godaddy.

My question is, should I manually export and upload the Wordpress install to the .com, or could I just point the .com at the .info? My primary concern is whether or not this could have a negative effect on SEO and page load time. What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: if you point your DNS at GoDaddy to your bluehost account you can easily swap the domains without having to reupload everything to a new host, then you have just to change the domain name on the wp config. Then you can easily redirect the .info to the .com as it is better that way so google knows it was moved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a few things here. First, If you have been using the .info rather than a dev box, the site may have already been indexed. Even if you relocate the content, you need to 301 the .info.

Id depends on how complex the site is. If you have just launched I would move it to the .com and either. 
A. 301 the .info to the .com
B. Go into webmaster tools and submit to remove the .info from Google's index (You will have to set that up if you have not).